# Sidekiq mailers queue not processing jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm using rails 4.2.10 and ruby 2.4.3. when I'm trying to start "mailers" queue, the process looks like running but it is not processing any job. Also in the sidekiq-web, the job appears in the busy tab for 1 minute and then disappear.

Please help.

Below are the logs

```
2018-01-19T09:42:07.756Z 26969 TID-1norfk ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-a078455af3409f04196e5f32 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.760Z 26969 TID-1nopkc ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-9d9e50ba76cabdadfa07bdb2 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.771Z 26969 TID-1nopqg ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-be7bc405d5c3f6ce22065ea8 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.772Z 26969 TID-1nos18 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-ba8df1375226e6e26df642ac INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.772Z 26969 TID-1noqr4 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-1515c7c6ce409038dc8c92da INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.773Z 26969 TID-1nor3c ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-97fd162d73cf434c086d8a10 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.773Z 26969 TID-1noobw ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-256d7664bbaaaaf83d99dc72 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.774Z 26969 TID-1nop84 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-cb086b61e1c9455dffa17a55 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.774Z 26969 TID-1irs1k ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-0864b36defdc9434eb1b2065 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.774Z 26969 TID-1noqx8 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-dc4690658e540cfb5bb93cc6 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.775Z 26969 TID-1noq8s ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-e28b3d3dbe0b257bc5febc5f INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.775Z 26969 TID-1noops ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-ef32300609c8a556718aa2aa INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.775Z 26969 TID-1nope8 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-6cc59784bd661bd76dee652b INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.775Z 26969 TID-1nor9g ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-969d4e43e0eb4d6e12dad4df INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.776Z 26969 TID-1nooi0 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-a35967d7d4ef58a5c0fc365c INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.776Z 26969 TID-1noojo ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-19e72b442b245fb6a2cb0bc0 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.776Z 26969 TID-1norog ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-1235978e66ea985794c131b1 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.777Z 26969 TID-1noq2o ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-d9d428705a048cbbd60f5603 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.777Z 26969 TID-1nopwk ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-25753f166c2fe7fad6355eff INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.777Z 26969 TID-1noo5s ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-e76c96e0c756f30b712c75c0 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.779Z 26969 TID-1noql0 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-fcd6f8cc86a5b7088a2253c0 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.779Z 26969 TID-1nop20 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-ccf7c458f22b4c64c248e79e INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.779Z 26969 TID-1noqew ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-f2b62f11d13a5068b8c3b57b INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.780Z 26969 TID-1norv4 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-1e3b86e34861567e64ef07d2 INFO: start
2018-01-19T09:42:07.780Z 26969 TID-1noovw ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-f572ef0da93a2ced8488ddff INFO: start
```

Comment: Check if there is any error in sidekiq.log

Comment: @Salil I have checked log, there is no error. Add log as well.